# call another class method

Tags: shipping-methods

in my class shipping in the file `app/code/community/Innnoexts/Core/Helper/shipping.php`p.

I want to call the method `getMethods()` in the file `app/code/local/Collinsharper/Purolator/Model/Source/Method.php`
I wrote this code

```
$test = Collinsharper::getModel(Purolator/Source/Method);
        var_dump($test->getMethods());
        echo '<br>'
```

;

but, I got this error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Collinsharper' not found in `/www/sites/mysite.com/files/html/app/code/community/Innoexts/Core/Helper/Shipping.php`

could you help me to give me the right instruction to call this method?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Magento don't use `Collinsharper::getModel(Purolator/Source/Method);` type .
`factory pattern and factory method`.There are lot issue on  your module.You need to basic study on magento [module structur](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table)e.

### Issue1:Magento factory call

Ii should be  `Mage::`  instead of `Collinsharper::`

`start the factory method` **Mage::**

It function is call at `Mage.php(magentodir/app)`

### Issue2:Magento modelprefix for a module

**getModel(Purolator** should not be this.It should be `getModel("modelprefix/`

**Model Prefix is define at** a`pp/code/community/Innnoexts/Core/etc/config.xml` under `<global>` tag

```
   <models>
        <modulePrefix><!-- guess that modulePrefix is your module model prefix -->
        <class>Innoexts_Core_Model</class>
        </modulePrefix>
    </models>
```

**Magento model factory method look like:**

Mage::getModel("modelprefix/modelsclass')

**Note:** Here  `Innoexts_Core` is  this `path of module`.

### Issue3:Factory method model class

As you have want to call function of `Method.php` from a`pp/code/local/Collinsharper/Purolator/Model/Source/Method` then it `Method.php` class should be

```
  Collinsharper_Purolator_Model_Source_Method
```

Then factory method is like

```
 Mage::getModel(modelPrefix/source_method)->getMethods();
```

**Collinsharper_Purolator_Model is modelPrefix** as config.xml define

and **source_method** emulate as `Source_Method`.

Please check at http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: thanks amit, this is what I used: $puroMethods = Mage::getModel(Collinsharper_Purolator_Model_Source_Method)->getMethods();

Comment: no you canot use this